# 'confusion matrix' for English phonemes

Tags: phonology

Is there a measure of distance somewhere that tells me that certain phoneme *A* is more "distant" or "different" to phoneme *B* than it is to phoneme *C* in English?

For example, that the phoneme /k/ is more close to phoneme /t/ that it is to /a/. (random values to create an example)

**Edit:**
As suggested by @Mitch, this is actually a 'confusion matrix' for English phonemes. Can anyone point to one of such tables?

Comment: I think you should ask first whether it is *true* that some phonemes are closer.  How do you know that /k/ and /t/ are closer than /k/ and /a/?

Comment: You can think of the [English phonemic chart](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf) as kind of a periodic table of the phonemes, with separate tables for consonants and vowels. One can actually envision a phonetic space, and measure distances (in millimeters or frequencies) between individual phones. But phonemes form simpler systems, more like the set of all the chemical elements than (say) the abstract space of all possible organic compounds, which is more like the set of all possible phones.

Comment: Obviously, /t/ is closer to /k/ than it is to /a/ because /a/ is in a different chart than /t/ and /k/ are. Both of them are consonants, while /a/ is a vowel. However, this is not a vast improvement in measurement, and it's not clear what "distance" between discrete entities should be measured, not in which dimensions, nor how many dimensions are necessary. Probly the best that can be achieved with phonemes is to say 'X is closer to Y than it is to Z' or else 'X is about as close to Y as it is to Z'

Comment: You are looking for a 'confusion matrix' for English phonemes. There exist these kinds of things used within speech recognition software. I'm not sure if there are any publicly available.

Comment: Indeed, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I'll edit the question to reflect this

Comment: @ElMarce: I'm googling for it, but can't find anything that really works well. You may want to look for tables just for vowels and separately just for consonants. There may be other words for 'confusion matrix'

Comment: found this: http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~dinoj/research/confmat.html

Comment: @ElMarce You can make an answer out of that (to encourage this to be a standing answer so useful later to someone else). Seems weird to answer ones own question, but it is allowed and works here.

Comment: The notion of "phoneme" as used in speech production and recognition is not the same idea at all as the term used in linguistics. Linguistic phonemic systems minimize phonemic inventory, while speech systems maximize them. The bigger the phoneme set, the better the discrimination.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After googling for a while for "confusion matrix", found this resource:

http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~dinoj/research/confmat.html

Perhaps is interesting to learn how to read a confusion matrix here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix

**Edit:** Thanks to J Trana for also pointing out the following papers:

- [Consonant And Vowel Confusion Patterns By
  American English Listeners](http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:60592:3/component/escidoc:60593/Cutler_2004_patterns.pdf) (
- [Patterns of English phoneme confusions by native
  and non-native listeners](http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:67125/component/escidoc:67126/Consonant%20And%20Vowel%20Confusion%20Patterns%20By.pdf)

Comment: This answer has, unfortunately, suffered from link rot, and is no longer useful.

Comment: [This](http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:60592:3/component/escidoc:60593/Cutler_2004_patterns.pdf) and [this](http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:67125/component/escidoc:67126/Consonant%20And%20Vowel%20Confusion%20Patterns%20By.pdf) have not only consonant but also vowel confusion matrices; I found them to be useful.

Comment: @J Trana: This is useful. Why not make the comment an answer?

Comment: Thanks! I felt your answer was a good one and already accepted long ago; this merely acts as a helpful addendum in the spirit of your answer rather than as a new standalone one. With these types of resource-finding questions, I tend to find there is a natural trend towards a community wiki-style answer over time.

Comment: I see, in that case, I will add your comment to my answer. With your permission, of course.

Answer (score 3):

The confusion matrix is highly dependent on the native language of the listener.

For example, a German speaker once asked me why we pronounce the German composer Bach's name with a /k/, when [bɑf] is clearly closer to [bɑx] than [bɑk]. It's not to modern English speakers. But it might have been closer in Middle English: the word *laugh*, which was originally pronounced with /x/, is now pronounced with an /f/ and not a /k/.

Similarly, [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297426/why-is-e-generally-transcribed-as-ay) and its answers show that Spanish speakers perceive /ɛ/ as the closest English phoneme to /e/, while American English speakers think it's /eɪ/.

And I suspect that /z/, /d/, and /v/ are the closest phonemes to /ð/ in various languages, because these are all substituted for /ð/ by foreigners learning English.

And even among native English speakers, people from California can't tell the difference between *Don* and *Dawn*, while people from the U.K. think they sound nothing alike.

Comment: Good point.  Does that mean there is no standard or objective measure of distances between phonemes within a language?  But this is often desirable for computational purposes.

Comment: With my answer, I was saying that there's no objective measure of distance between phonemes that holds across various languages. But I wouldn't be surprised if speakers of a single dialect of a language perceived there's a consistent measure of distance between phonemes. I don't know whether anybody has studied this.

Comment: Actually, the links in El Marce's answer see to imply that speakers of a single dialect have a reasonably consistent measure of distance between phonemes, although I'd like to see a study confirming that.